# Group by one field and count distinct values of another

Tags: mongodb

There are a number of questions on SO that are like this one, but I'm not sure which (if any) are the same as my question.

I have a collection

```
{name: 'amy', age:19}
{name: 'bob', age:80}
{name: 'bob', age:80}
{name: 'chris', age:31}
{name: 'chris', age:20}
```

and I would like to get the number of **distinct** `age` values for each `name`. So I'd like to return

```
{'amy': 1, 'bob': 1, 'chris': 2}
```

I've been trying `aggregate` queries with `group` and `sum`, but I can't quite get it right.

Answer (score 6):

You can aggregate as below, the key is to use: [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator, to accumulate distinct ages, and then use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator to get the number of distinct ages, per name(group).

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$name","ages":{$addToSet:"$age"}}},
{$project:{"name":"$_id","_id":0,"count":{$size:"$ages"}}}
])
```